# How can we access read and write XML at same time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file

In my application i am creating a XML file for every 15secs at admin side.
For creating the XML i have used the string builder to XML.

```
File.WriteAllText("D:\\FE_Display.xml", StringBuilder.ToString())
```

The same file i used to display in Grid  on Front end for every 15 secs. This file minimum 10memebrs using at same time at Front end.The below code is used for front end.

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()  

ds.ReadXml("d://FE_Display.xml")
Try
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Grid1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        Grid1.DataBind()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

If the both events(read and write) happens at same time  i am getting below error

> the process cannot access the file 'FE_Display.xml' because it is being used by another process

Comment: Now you know why databases exists. As a solution you can use threads or some kind of flag to synchronize the access using Monitor (Enter and Exit)

Comment: Why did you put a C# tag? it's VB.NET question.

Comment: I would wrap both sets of code with a Loop that tested for success (or didn't experience failure.) In the retry loop include Application.DoEvents to reduce pressure on the CPUs during a retry. Worst case you'll be some time measured in milliseconds off.

Comment: Rather than use Application.DoEvents() (there are many posts on why that is usually undesirable), I suggest putting the file reading and writing routines in a background thread and re-try the file operation until it works (not forgetting a sanity counter), that way you can use Thread.Sleep(100) (example time) in the loop without affecting the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `FileShare.ReadWrite` option when opening the file for writing.

Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading or writing. If this flag is not specified, any request to open the file for reading or writing (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed. However, even if this flag is specified, additional permissions might still be needed to access the file.

Take from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx

Example when opening:

```
var filestream = File.Open(fileName,
                            FileMode.Open,
                            FileAccess.Read,
                            FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Then your subsequent read of the file can open without error.

Answer (score 2):

Files are mutually exclusive usually unless you provide [FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx). you can Read a file keep it in memory then write it.

`Reading` and `Writing` at the sametime doesn't makes sense(at least for xml) since xml has to be well formatted. when you write and read at the same time you'll get unexpected results.

Best way is

1. Open the file, consume it an close it.
2. Open the file, write to it.

Comment: Can I know If file is open mode for write,is it possible to read same time?

Comment: I agree with this practice with reading and writing at the same time.  I am not sure why the file is being written every 15 seconds.

Comment: Yes you can but while opening the file you have to specify `FileShare.ReadWrite or FileShare.Read` atleast

Comment: @JonRaynor That OP only knows

Comment: @Sree Why do you want to access or create a file every **15** seconds?

Comment: This is for bidding site,So i need to show bidding history for every 15 secs,If i use the DB instead of XML it will effect on my server.